# R with C++ (QtCreator, Windows, Rcpp, RInside)

Tags: c++, windows, qt-creator, rcpp, rinside

I have a problem when it comes to using R within the C++ code. I'd like to create UI in c++ and do all needed calculations in R. So i've found stuff like Rcpp and RInside and even though i've read a lot from Dirk Eddelbuettel's site, i'm not able to compile even the easiest program from examples attached to RInside. Obviously there is a problem with QtCreator config, I've been trying to make it right, but with no success. What i'm asking for would be step-by-step explanation of QT adjustment for R. What i already have:

- binary for windows (installed)
- RTools (installed)
- QtCreator with MinGW (installed)
- RInside and Rcpp (installed with install.packages(c("Rcpp", "RInside")) )

To be more specific, i've done everything from here: 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rcpp-on-windows-7-for-r-and-c-integration/

What i would like to do is to create a new project in Qt, write it in c++ and some of the functions would use R for calculations and plot. So what should i do?

Those are the errors:
oi41.tinypic.com/20stzsj.jpg

And when i added LIBS errors are gone, but program does nothing:
http://oi44.tinypic.com/qnk5sp.jpg

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "C:\...\qtdensity.h:11: error: RInside.h: No such file or directory
 #include <RInside.h>"

so the next thing i do is to add the include path to .pro file like this:
INCLUDEPATH += "......"

after this, i get other error, this time with R.h, so i add this one too, and after this when i try to compile the program i get like 3 thousand of errors

Comment: Its hard to know the solution if you don't tell us the actual build errors you have

Comment: Those are the errors:
http://oi41.tinypic.com/20stzsj.jpg

Comment: So you are not linking the library that contains this R stuff

Comment: Complete and tested compile and link instructions come with all the examples.  Study what the standard `qmake && make` solution does, then adapt your Qt Creator settings accordingly.

Comment: Ok, once i add include paths as well as the lib paths to my .pro file it compiles and even runs, but still does nowthing, also it shows smth like "Can't get handle to subprocess because of the wrong parameter" any ideas? (i'm still trying to run the simple hello world program)

Comment: http://oi42.tinypic.com/wu1pe.jpg

Comment: I've switched to Linux because i couldn't make it working. It's fine now.