# How to embed R in a c++ cli program

Tags: c++, r, winforms, command-line-interface

I'd like to embed R into a c++ winforms app. It will output the graphs to a pictureBox, and output the numbers to a richTextBox. It takes commands from a textbox. I tried the header file RInside.h, but there is no such file. 
Pseudo code:

```
 #include <someDirToImbedR>
 ExecuteButton_Click(args) {
 RExecute(commandTextBox->Text);
 outputGraphPictureBox->Load(output_graph);
 richTextBox1->Text = OutputString; 
 }
```

Comment: do you have R installed?

Comment: Yes, I have R installed

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268223/r-with-c-qtcreator-windows-rcpp-rinside) on SO concerning (may be) the same problem.

Here is the [Link](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside/html/index.html) to a repository by Dirk Eddelbuettel. It has even [sample code](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside/html/dir_3d6c80e050bc5f3a6af729da3f901c0d.html) in c++ to try for yourself.

Also this [Link](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/inst/include/RInside.h?root=rinside&view=log) might be helpful.

Hope this can bring you on track. Unfortunately I personally used R only in C#.